# Query a month inside array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Problem I'm trying to solve is querying an array of documents using mongoose's find model function. My documents look something like this:

```
{
  name: "John",
  courses: [
    {
      name: "CS",
      enrolled: 2015-12-12T00:00:00.000+00:00,
      ...,
    },
    {
      name: "Math",
      enrolled: 2016-10-12T00:00:00.000+00:00,
      ...,
    },
    {
      name: "History",
      enrolled: 2017-09-12T00:00:00.000+00:00,
      ...,
    },
    ...,
  ]
}
```

So, issue here is I'm trying to query all those documents in which one of the subdocuments in the array has a "enrolled" field which matches a specific month for the date it holds. For instance, find all documents where the person enrolled to a course in December (month 12)

I know it is possible to do something like the following whenever "enroll" is a date field inside the document.

`{$expr: {$eq: [{$month: "$enroll"}, 12]}}`

The problem is the date field is inside the array and embedded in the subdocument. I **DO NOT** want to use aggregation pipelines since I need to retrieve the whole document with mongoose's find model function.

Any ideas on how to proceed? Thank you!

Comment: You can not, because when you use positional operator `$` in find(), it will give only one matching find in result [check](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gdLvMIdR_vd), you need to go with aggregate()

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone. Ended up altering my document structure....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you struggled with the query, you can use `$filter` to eliminate unwanted objects.

```
{
    "$project": {
      name: 1,
      courses: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$courses",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.enrolled",
              "2016-10-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QbEBzIfUY2f)

Comment: I wouldn't want to use aggregation since I need to do the queries with a find function :/

Comment: I dont think there might be some ways to do without aggregation

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve whole document while also performing the match is certainly possible with aggregation.

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      coursesCopy: "$courses"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$courses"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$month": "$courses.enrolled"
          },
          12
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      courses: {
        $first: "$coursesCopy"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

[Playground link -Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q919u3u4cs5)